# .tpl using php cant access the value that is store on index

Tags: php, laravel, oop, smarty

```
{LOOP: QUESTIONS}
  <div class="submit-field">
    <h5>{VALUE}</h5>
    <input name="answers[]" required="">
  </div>
{/LOOP: QUESTIONS}
```

PHP code:

```php
$item_questions = ['Question 1', 'Questions 2']
$page->SetLoop('QUESTIONS', $item_questions);
```

How do I show question value on this?

Comment: Please use the correct tags. This has nothing to do with the `Task Parallel Library`

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty, you need to use the [`foreach`](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) loop:

```
{foreach from=$QUESTIONS item=question}
  <div class="submit-field">
    <h5>{$question}</h5>
    <input name="answers[]" required />
  </div>
{/foreach}
```